# How long has my display stayed on?

Tags: windows-10, display

Is there a way to find out for how long the display of my laptop has actually stayed on?

It turns off automatically when left idle for a while, or when I close the lid (I've set it not to sleep on lid closing). I rarely shut it down or put it to sleep, if ever.

I just wanna find out how long has the screen stayed on. Like, if I had to guess I'd say it probably stays on ~12 hrs a day. But I'm not really sure. That's why I wanted find out if there's an actual number (hrs/mins) saved somewhere or can be extracted/inferred somehow.

Is it possible find this information?

I'm on Windows 10 Pro x64

Comment: Can't answer this question, because I'm not 100% sure about this, but I think you cannot extract that information from the system. System's idle time is probably easier to get, but not sure about either. Is there a deeper reason why do you need this information?